# Can't find modules installed via virtualenv on windows

Tags: python, virtualenv

I'm running virtualenv on Windows 7 and I created a virtual environment for python 2.7 and installed some modules but I can't seem to import it.

1) venv\scripts\activate

2) pip2 install requests

```
(I the following message: get Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): requests in c:\users\dan\desktop\python\bulkphotos\venv\lib\site-packages)
```

3) when I try to import this on the interactive shell, I get the following error

```
(venv) C:\Users\Dan\Desktop\Python\bulkphotos>py
Python 2.7.10 (default, May 23 2015, 09:40:32) [MSC v.1500 32 bit (Intel)] on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import requests
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: No module named requests
```

4) I've tried searching SO but the other answers seem to be applicable for a mac (e.g. accidentally installing via sudo). When I do pip2 list, the module is present, so I don't understand why I can't access it.

```
(venv) C:\Users\Dan\Desktop\Python\bulkphotos>pip2 list
google-api-python-client (1.4.1)
httplib2 (0.9.1)
oauth2client (1.4.12)
pip (7.1.0)
pyasn1 (0.1.8)
pyasn1-modules (0.0.7)
requests (2.7.0)
rsa (3.2)
setuptools (18.0.1)
simplejson (3.8.0)
six (1.9.0)
uritemplate (0.6)
wheel (0.24.0)

(venv) C:\Users\Dan\Desktop\Python\bulkphotos>pip2 show requests
---
Metadata-Version: 2.0
Name: requests
Version: 2.7.0
Summary: Python HTTP for Humans.
Home-page: http://python-requests.org
Author: Kenneth Reitz
Author-email: me@kennethreitz.com
License: Apache 2.0
Location: c:\users\dan\desktop\python\bulkphotos\venv\lib\site-packages
Requires:

(venv) C:\Users\Dan\Desktop\Python\bulkphotos>
```

Does anyone know how to solve this problem?

EDIT
The results of running sys.path on the interactive shell

```
['', 'C:\\windows\\system32\\python27.zip', 'C:\\Python27\\DLLs', 'C:\\Python27\\lib', 'C:\\Python27\\lib\\plat-win', 'C:\\Python27\\lib\\lib-tk', 'C:\\Python27', 'C:\\Python27\\lib\\site-packages']
```

The results of running where py and where python

```
(venv) C:\Users\Dan\Desktop\Python\bulkphotos>where py
C:\Windows\py.exe

(venv) C:\Users\Dan\Desktop\Python\bulkphotos>where python
C:\Users\Dan\Desktop\Python\bulkphotos\venv\Scripts\python.exe
C:\Python27\python.exe
C:\Python34\python.exe
```

Comment: From the python interpreter, can you run "import sys" then "sys.path" and post the results?  Also, from your command line can you run "where py" and also "where python"?

Comment: @jlyoung Thank you for your help, and I've added the results to my post. The funny thing of "where py" is the my gobal path for python is actually "C:\python27\python.exe", not sure why it is pointing to "C:\Windows\py.exe" and not either to venv

Comment: It looks like the virtualenv doesn't copy the Windows launcher `py.exe` to its `Scripts` folder. Does the import error occur when you launch interpreter by calling `python` from command line (instead of `py`)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The Windows Python launcher [PEP 397](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0397/) is not aware of the active virtual env. See [PEP 486](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0486/) for details.

Try to launch Python interpreter by executing `python` instead of `py`.

Answer (score 1):

I dont know why these packages are not imported,

But you can debug it by viewing your pythonpath using,

```
python -c "import sys; print sys.path"
```

You can append optional path to `sys.path`.

Comment: Thank you for your comments, and I've added the path to my original post.